# Does surface dock save data?

Tags: windows, storage, microsoft-surface, data-transfer, docking-station

Does the surface dock keep any user data on it that is transmitted through it to a monitor from a laptop? I assume there is no internal ram or storage that would capture any display data, as there is t really a reset option, but I just wanted to be sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Does surface dock save data?**

No. A dock is a series of output and extra input ports to connect additional peripheral devices.  It will normally have a power supply to power the laptop when attached to the dock.

Other than switching devices and circuitry, there are no smarts inside a dock (none that I have known over the years).

So it cannot and therefore does not save data.

Comment: "there are no smarts": there are firmware updates available for Surface Docks, so there will be some sort of microcontroller or microprocessor inside.

Comment: There are firmware updates - true but firmware does not save data - it just looks after the circuitry for connection into the laptop and changes required for that.